# Foursquare (411) Length Required error with SharpSquare api

Tags: c#, api, foursquare

We've been using the Foursquare SharpSquare api to add checkins with success.  We recently noticed that we're getting a "(411) Length Required" error.  We get this error most of the time now, but once in a while it will post successfully.  The general consensus to fix this error seem to be to add Content-Length=0 to the header, but i'm not sure if that's possible with SharpSquare.  Any ideas?

Comment: Which API endpoint are you trying to call?

Comment: 'checkins', just trying to Add a Checkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the SharpSquare api does not properly add a Content-length header. If this is not possible from using the SharpSquare API, you may need to update the SharpSquare source so this is performed correctly, or craft your own HTTP request without using the SharpSquare API.